# withCheckedContinuation and [weak self] in Swift Concurrency?

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, task, swift-concurrency, strong-reference-cycle

Code example:

```swift
func someAsyncFunc() async {
    loadingTask?.cancel()
    return await withCheckedContinuation { [weak self] checkedContinuation in
        guard let self else {
            return
        }
        loadingTask = Task { [weak self] in
            guard let self else {
                return
            }
            //some code with self
            checkedContinuation.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that one of `[weak self]` calls is extra - this example just shows 2 possible code chunks where it can be placed.

According to one documentation article `withCheckedContinuation` should always call `checkedContinuation.resume()`, according to another documentation article you should use `[weak self]` to avoid strong reference cycles. But how to use both of them simultaneously?

If I leave code AS-IS then `checkedContinuation.resume()` may not be called and it leads to memory leaks. If I don't use `[weak self]` it leads to retain cycles which lead to memory leaks too. I also can't just replace `withCheckedContinuation` with `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` because it raises code complexity and also means I should forget about `withCheckedContinuation` (because any similar method may contain `[weak self]`).

Comment: Why do you have a `Task` in a `withCheckedContinuation`? How about just `await` the `Task` directly?

Comment: 1)how to use it directly? I tried various code combinations but always get compilation errors or at least warnings; 2)instead of `Task` there may be another async func (for example, a func with completion block) but the problem with `[weak self]` persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations:

1. We generally use `[weak self]` to avoid strong reference cycles. There is no persistent strong reference cycle here, so `[weak self]` is not needed.
2. Sometimes we used `[weak self]` pattern in those situations where there was not a persistent strong reference cycle, but just a temporary reference to `self` while the asynchronous task is running.

   But even in this case, using `[weak self]` is not well advised. Nowadays, rather than worrying about the lifespan of `self`, we shift our attention to the lifespan of the asynchronous task. Specifically, we make sure we just cancel the the asynchronous work as soon as its results are no longer needed. This renders `[weak self]` pattern moot.

   Back in the days of GCD, cancelation was clumsy. But Swift concurrency offers first-class cancelation support, so we should embrace that, canceling the task when the view is dismissed (e.g., in UIKit/AppKit in `viewDidDisappear`, in SwiftUI in `.onDisappear`).
3. All of that having been said, let’s say that you really wanted to do something like contemplated in your question. (It is unnecessary and a bad design, but let us discuss it just as a thought exercise.)

   Consider your code snippet:

   ```swift
   func someAsyncFunc() async {
       loadingTask?.cancel()
       return await withCheckedContinuation { [weak self] checkedContinuation in
           guard let self else {
               return
           }
           loadingTask = Task { [weak self] in
               guard let self else {
                   return
               }
               //some code with self
               checkedContinuation.resume()
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   There are two problems with this `guard let self else { return }` pattern:

   - First, tasks generally start immediately, so you generally will pass the `guard` statements before `self` is possibly deinitialized, so these `guard` statements will not accomplish anything.
   - Second, as you noted, in these `guard` statements, you are returning without calling `resume`, which is invalid. In `withCheckedContinuation`, you *must* `resume` once and only once. But you are returning without ever calling `resume`. If this happens (which is exceedingly unlikely, given my first point), the checked continuation will report an error. You must `resume` the continuation before you `return` in these `guard` statements (assuming you `guard` at all).
4. Note, when adopting cancelation patterns, you would generally use `withTaskCancellationHandler`, `try Task.checkCancellation()`, test `Task.isCancelled()`, etc., in order to respond to the cancelation. But we would need to see the “some code with self” to advise further (and would probably be best addressed in a separate question). If you do not implement cancelation support, your `task.cancel()` will not accomplish anything.

But, again, do not just blindly insert `[weak self]` pattern for fear of a potential strong reference cycle risk, as there is no strong reference cycle here and it is a bit of an antipattern in Swift concurrency. One should adopt cancelation patterns, instead.

Answer (score 0):

`with*Continuation` is for wrapping legacy code that uses completion blocks and so on in an asynchronous context. Your preferred course of action would be to not need to use it at all, and have the entire function operate in the calling asynchronous context (which should then also support cascading cancellation, instead of having to manage a task separately).

You are also running the risk of failing to resume the continuation if `someAsyncFunc` is called repeatedly, which is more weight behind just using async functions directly.

If after all that, you still have a good reason for continuing to use continuations, you can treat the deallocation of self as equivalent to a cancellation, and throw `CancellationError`, or you can resume the continuation with a value of `Void` (`()`), since that is the return type of the overall function.